# ¿Esta bien que el tipo de relacion sea de dependencia cuando lo unico que conoce una clase de la otra es un atributo?

Tags: poo

Estoy diseñando una especie de CMS para un herbario (Es un proyecto académico), estaba haciendo el diagrama de clases, para ser mas especifico el diagrama de clases de las entidades que van a cumplir el papel de modelo en la arquitectura de mi aplicación.

Me preguntaba si es correcto que que las relaciones que mostrare a continuación entre las clases sea de tipo dependencia.

El concepto que tengo de este tipo de relación es el siguiente:

> Relación (más débil que una asociación) que muestra la relación entre
>   un cliente y el proveedor de un servicio usado por el cliente.
>   -Cliente es el objeto que solicita un servicio.  -Servidor es el objeto que provee el servicio solicitado.

El ejemplo que me ofrecía ese libro es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este concepto lo recupere de: https://elvex.ugr.es/decsai/java/pdf/3C-Relaciones.pdf

Aquí la ecuación hace uso de la función sqrt, aparte de esto no conoce nada de la otra clase, y a diferencia de los otros tipos de relaciones lo que noto es que ecuación no contendría una referencia a un Objeto Math en una relación de dependencia.

Mientras que mi diagrama es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Llegue a la conclusión de que las clases (Almenos las de mi capa de Modelo) deberían estar relacionadas por dependencia ya que solo utilizo el atributo  (el id) de una clase en otra y no contengo una referencia a un objeto lo cual si podría generar un tipo de relación como la asociación,composición o agregación...

En mi caso el servicio que provee una clase a la otra seria el de proporcionarle su id, no se si esta bien verlo de esa forma...Me gustaría que me dijeran si estoy en lo correcto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asociacion:
Los objetos (referencias) si bien es cierto que un objeto A esta contenido en un objeto B, tambien podria estarlo en un objeto C y tambien en un objeto D y asi todo el rato,
el que se destruya el objeto contenedor no afectara al objeto contenido, seguira existiendo en el programa (la referencia de este objeto).

Agregacion:
Un objeto solo puede estar contenido en otro, pero su existencia no depende del objeto contenedor. si la referencia del objeto que contiene al otro se destruye, no se destruira el objeto contenido.

Composicion:
Un objeto solo puede estar contenido en otro, su existencia esta ligada directamente al objeto contenedor, si se destruye la referencia del objeto contenedor ya no hay razon para que exista la referencia del objeto contenido, tambien se eliminara segun esta relacion.

Para saber si estas tomando el tipo de relacion correcta debes tener en cuenta los aspectos que te ofrecen estos tipos de relaciones es decir, ¿Mi objeto A sobrevivira y tiene sentido que sobreviva si mi objeto B se destruye? ¿Una referencia de A podria estar contenida en varias referencias al mismo tiempo?, conociendo estos conceptos sabras si estas tomando la relacion correcta.